# Cant populate the columns correctly in of an HTML table?

Tags: java, html-table, filewriter

I have a program that creates an HTML table and populates the data from the table into specific columns. Currently my program puts all the data in one column and leaves the others blank. Need help populating each column with the required data. I have included part of the code as well as an image of my output table. Please not their are others issues regarding the data type thats populating the columns but I'd like to start with the issue outlined above first.

```
public class HtmlDataTable {

    private static final String FileDemo = null;



    public static void writehtmltable(Set<String> filenameSet){
        if (filenameSet == null)
            return;

        //creates table in the following path
        File htmltable = new File("C:/test/Output.html");

        try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(htmltable))) {

            //write html data table
            bw.write(htmltop);
            // "<th>POM File Data</TH> <TH>Lib Directory Files</TH> <TH>Missing Jarfiles</TH>"; 

            for (String jarfilename : filenameSet) {

                String lines="<tr>  <td> </td>  <td> </td> <td>"+ jarfilename + "</td> </tr>"; // to fill Missing jarfile column

                String line="<tr>  <td> </td>  <td> </td> <td>"+ jarfilename + "</td> </tr>";// to fill lib directory file column
                String lin="<tr>  <td> </td>  <td> </td> <td>"+ jarfilename + "</td> </tr>";// to fill the Pom File column
                bw.write(lines);
                bw.write(line);
                bw.write(lin);

            }


            bw.write(htmlbottom);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();


        }

    }

    // Code for HTML Table
    private static String htmltop = "<!DOCTYPE html>\n"+
                                     "<html>\n"+

                                        "<head>"+
                                        "<title>Jar Filename Existance Check</title>"+
                                        "<style>"+
                                        "table, th, td {"+
                                        "    border: 2px solid black;"+
                                        "}"+
                                        "</style>"+
                                        "</head>"+
                                        "<body>"+
                                        "<table>\n"+
                                        "   <tr>     <th colspan='100'>" +
                                        "<h3><br>Jarfilename Existance Check</h3>      </th>   </tr>" +
                                        "<th>POM File Data</th> <th>Lib Directory Files</th> <th>Missing Jarfiles</th>"; 


    private static String htmlbottom = "</table></body></html>"; 


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new HtmlDataTable().writehtmltable(null);
    }


}
```

[image: Output written to table]

Comment: I'm very confused. Right now you're putting the same jarname in the same column three times in a row - which is exactly what your output it. `String lin="<tr>  <td> </td>  <td> </td> <td>"+ jarfilename + "</td> </tr>";` Two empty `td`s followed by the jar name.

Comment: I'd like to have that data populate each column once instead of the same column 3 times.

Comment: then you don't need 3 lines.just one is enough 
`String lines="<tr>   <td>"+ jarfilename + "</td> <td>"+ jarfilename + "</td> <td>"+ jarfilename + "</td> </tr>"`

Comment: So then just remove the `line` and `lin` variables and don't write them out. Your code pretty plainly write the same info out three times. Solution? Don't write it out three times.

Comment: Well, don't write three lines that have the same content, and iterate over a collection that actually holds all three items for each line. You are only iterating on the jar file names collection, so jar file names is all you have.

Comment: @FullNelson I've rolled back your recent edit - that should be asked as a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the content once in the furthest column:

```
for (String jarfilename : filenameSet) {
            String lines="<tr>  <td> </td>  <td> </td> <td>"+ jarfilename +  "</td> </tr>";
            bw.write(lines);
        }
```

If you want the same info in all three columns:

```
for (String jarfilename : filenameSet) {
            String lines="<tr>  <td>"+ jarfilename + "</td>  <td>"+ jarfilename + " </td> <td>"+ jarfilename +  "</td> </tr>";
            bw.write(lines);
        }
```

You're seeing the same content repeated three times *because that's what your code is written to do* - you're writing writing the same content to the table three times. If you remove the extra write commands (and again, I can't stress this enough, they *are writing the same content three times in a row*) you won't see the extra table rows.

Comment: thanks for your help this resolved the issue of populating the columns.

Comment: I'm aware that Im seeing the code 3 times thats the next issue that I need to resolve. Should I post a new question or sesolve it here?

Comment: That should be posted as a new question. I encourage you to check out the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to learn more about Stack Overflow and how it works. Glad that I was able to help, we ask that you indicated that the problem has been solved by accepting an answer (click the green checkmark next to the answer that helped you solve the problem).

Comment: Oh, and if you have any more questions about Stack Overflow itself, please feel free to visit [meta].

Answer (score 0):

That is happening because you have not set any data to be displayed for those columns. `<td> </td>`

You have not mentioned what data you want to put there. From where that data comes.

Just like `<td>"+ jarfilename + "</td>`, you need to write something (direct content or some java variable) inside your empty td tags here `<td> </td>`

Comment: The data I'd like to add there is causing me an entirely different issue so for now I'd like to resolve the issue of populating the columns correctly. What code am I missing in terms of setting the data to be written to those columns?